# WiFi LAN and Ad hoc using USB LAN at the same time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ad-hoc-network

I have a laptop with WiFi and a USB LAN port. I wish to connect to our wireless router through my WiFi and to my NAS through cross cable using my USB LAN port (ad hoc or peer to peer local networking). Is this setup possible? What are the things i need to consider? Is it possible to share my laptop's connection to internet with my NAS?

EDIT:
Actually I'm skeptic on this because I have an office laptop that automatically disconnects its WiFi whenever I plug it in a wired LAN port.

Comment: Yes you can, it's just a matter of configuriong your cards with the right addresses and make sure the routing table is properly set. What Operating System ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 home premium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [network bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/create-network-bridge):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEAC2.jpg]

Comment: Updated the question. Do you think having a wired connection won't drop my WiFi connection?

Comment: I don't think windows does that. Do you have a HP driver or other 3rd party control for your wireless?

Comment: It seems it only happens to my office laptop. Not sure why. Yes it has 3rd party control Intel Wireless.